# how to check image behaviuor

Tags: asp.net

here is my image width and size code which is work perfectly but problem is that when i pass null fileupload it give me error 'argument not valid ' but i want pass null value also how will i do

```
HttpPostedFile fil = this.FileUp.PostedFile;
                 System.Drawing.Image uploadimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fil.InputStream);
                 if (uploadimage.Height > 155 || uploadimage.Width > 124)
                 {
                     lblErrorMsg.Visible = true;
                     lblErrorMsg.Text = "<font class='orange'>Height and width not accpetable</font>";
                     return;

                 }
```

Comment: my question is i want pass blank path also if i don't want select image or any doc file this code should allow me

Comment: you pass null from what to what?

Comment: Are the uploaded files going into a database? I would make sure the field can accept NULLS.

Comment: how you going to check the uploadimage.Height with passing a null ??

Comment: i have one application where i filled all information but im think upload image is not mandatory so im not insert image that time this error come but when i upload image it work fine but null cannot take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then check the `HasFile` property of the FileUpload control before continuing...

```
if (this.FileUp.PostedFile.HasFile)
{
  // continue...
}
```

check here: [FileUpload.HasFile Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx)